# Delimiters for text search in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, search, text

I am trying mongoDB text search in mongoDB server version 2.6.3. When I perform a text search with below query

```
db.collection.find({"$text" : {"$search" : "a@b"}})
```

I am getting as results documents which contain a or b, which means I am getting results for

```
db.collection.find({"$text" : {"$search" : "a b"}})
```

I am guessing mongo text parser is considering `'@'` character as delimiter and replacing it with a space. Is there a way we can specify that `'@'` character shouldn't be considered as a delimiter?

Answer (score 2):

To **[match on a phrase](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/text/#phrases)**, as opposed to individual terms, enclose the phrase in escaped double quotes `(\")`, as in:

```
"\"a@b\""
```

So your query would look like:

```
db.collection.find({"$text" : {"$search" : "\"a@b\""}})
```

For example:

```
db.collection.insert([
    {"x": "a@b"},
    {"x": "a b"},
    {"x": "b"},
    {"x": "a"}
]);

db.collection.createIndex({ x: "text"});
```

The query `db.collection.find({"$text" : {"$search" : "\"a@b\""}})` returns

```
/* 0 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5549ddce180e849972939043"),
    "x" : "a@b"
}
```

Comment: You can read more about this in [the docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/text/#search-for-a-phrase)

Comment: @chridam making it as a phrase search as you mentioned will work. But this solution requires making every query as a phrase, which means even if I want to search for "a b" I would end up searching for \"a b\".                 I am looking for a general solution where I should be able to specify the set of delimiters such that it won't split on special characters other than the specified set of delimiters. Say  if I specify delimiter characters as "-", then if the query is "a-b", mongo should parse it as "a b". If the query is "a@b" it should remain as "a@b". Now even "a@b" is parsed as "a b"

Comment: I have exactly the same issue. Still no solution 5 years later :(